# Migrated ASP.NET Membership-Based App Won't Authenticate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have an ASP.NET app that uses the Membership provider. I just copied the app and associated database to a new server, and now I can't log into it. I've confirmed the database connection string is correct and that the app can talk to the database - the problem is with the Membership provider somewhere.

On both servers the app is set to use ASP.NET 4.0; the old server is running IIS 7.0, and the new is IIS 7.5. The app was copied over using the Web Deploy tool, so it's identical on both servers.

After reading [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx) - which seems to describe the problem exactly and indicates the issue could be due to the `applicationName` attribute being set differently on each server - I checked on the old and new server, and confirmed that the `applicationName` in config was set to the same value ("/") on both servers - here's the full config entry under `<membership>`:

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
 type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
 connectionStringName="Default"
 enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
 enablePasswordReset="true"
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
 requiresUniqueEmail="false"
 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
 minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
 passwordAttemptWindow="10"
 applicationName="/" />
```

I also checked in the aspnet_Applications table, and there is a single record with ApplicationName='/' and LoweredApplicationName='/' - so the `applicationName` value from the config file is being honoured.

My next thought was that somehow the passwords are being encrypted using the machineKey for the old server, which is different to the machineKey on the new server. However, as you can see in the above config entry, the `passwordFormat` key is not set in config (on either server). I couldn't find any documentation to indicate the default value of this attribute, but on the database table aspnet_Membership, every record has `PasswordFormat` set to 1, which [according to this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx) indicates the passwords are hashed, and not encrypted.

Nevertheless, I investigated whether I could copy the machineKey from one server to another - but the old server is set to AutoGenerate, so I don't know if this is even possible. And if it is, I don't think it'll help as (AFAIK) the machineKey isn't involved in hashing.

One last thing - the app that handles this is in a subfolder of another app. I don't think that makes any difference but I thought I'd mention it. The child app is not set to be an application in IIS, it's just a folder.

All in all, I'm not sure how to proceed. As far as I can tell the app (on both servers) is hashing the passwords, not encrypting them, and so it should just move across fine. I'd appreciate any advice on what to check .

Comment: Could you create a new user and check whether the new user is able to authenticate?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, I just tried this and new users can authenticate fine, so obviously there's some key that's different somewhere. I also tried getting the machine key from the old server and adding it into the web.config file, which made no difference either.